# How to obtain reactant lifetime using transition state theory?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, computational-chemistry

[I've read this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jacs.5b00014) and the authors calculate life times of an intermediate using Quasi-Classical-Trajectories (QCT), RRKM and transition state theory (TST). Table 3 on page 4755 show the results.

If I understand correctly for the QCT calculations they take all (several hundred in that case) trajectories and just do statistical analysis of the lifetime of that intermediate. That perfectly makes sense and they come up with a value +/- error.

For TST they also calculate a lifetime of that intermediate, assuming it is in equilibrium with it's surrounding. This makes me think that they used the reaction barrier from intermediate to product for their calculation of the lifetime. How to do this? Up to now I've only used TST in combination with Eyring equation for calculation of rate constants.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, there are two things that I should answer for you.

Calculating rate constants with any trajectory methods is different than using TST. In fact, the whole point of using QCT is so we can account for nonstatistical effects. These nonstatistical effects are usually extremely important, as it is also mentioned in the article

> ... This dynamic matching leads to pronounced nonstatistical effects
>   on the lifetimes...

Any time you are using TST, you are assuming there are no nonstatistical effects whatsoever. This approximation is probably never true, but it leads to surprisingly good numerical results. The way you calculate reaction rates in QCT is by integrating the reaction probability using a Monte Carlo integration formula, cleverly sampling the initial conditions of the reactants. I usually recommend a good book of [W. Miller](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-0644-4). The book itself is a bit outdated, but the derivation by Porter and Raff in the first chapter is beautiful.

Now you asked about the determination of the lifetime. The article, as I understand it, talks mostly about the lifetime of the activated complex. This can be done because in QCT we know the coordinates of atoms in every single timestep, so we can compare them to some given values to decide whether we are in the activated complex region or not. From the article:

> Transition zones were defined for the C–C forming (3‡) and the C–N breaking (5‡) steps (see Supporting Information for details). [...] The lifetime of 
>    intermediate 4b was defined as the elapsed time between departure from the transition zone 3b‡ and entrance in transition zones 5b‡

So, long story short: QCT determines lifetimes differently from TST, this is because TST is inherently statistical, while QCT also considers nonstatistical effects. Instead, QCT calculations rely on defining geometries for different states, and simply calculating how many integration steps the system spends there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand and/or knew the things you explained here and it doesn't really answers my question. I know how to calculate a rate constant using TST (eyring equation) and I know how to determine the lifetime of this intermediate using QCT. What I don't know is how to calculate the lifetime using TST (and how to calculate rate constants using a trajectory - if that's even possible). How do I get to the lifetime of this intermediate using TST?

Comment: As for calculating the rate constant by QCT, I'd still refer you to the Raff-Porter chapter I linked earlier, it is well explained there. As I mentioned in my comment, you do a Monte Carlo sampling of the initial condition, and if you choose the right distributions, then the reaction rate calculation reduces to counting the ratio of reactive collisions to nonreactive collisions. Note that this is true only for a well-derived Monte Carlo sampling, that is what is found in the book I mentioned earlier. Another reference can be found at Gaussan help page: http://gaussian.com/glossary/hase96/

Comment: I am not quite sure about determining the lifetime of the activated complex by TST calculations, as I have no real experience in TST methods. I have a hard time imagining an activated complex with a non-zero lifetime tho. It is a local energy maximum, thus a metastable configuration. I'd make a wild guess that it can have no lifetime whatsoever. Someone who is more experienced than me should correct me tho.

Comment: thanks, this sounds very interesting I will look into that. Let's see if someone else knows how to do this. I'm able to calculate the lifetime of the activated complex but not the reactant.

Comment: If you can calculate the reaction rate, isn't the reactant lifetime just the reciprocal of the rate coefficient?

Comment: yeah that's what I figured out in the last hour, just similar to lifetime of radioactive particles. It does make sense, but somehow the numbers don't add upvery nicely. For whatever reason I'm always a little bit off (7600 instead of 7000 for example). I have to check with their actual numbers from the SI to confirm. But thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you off compared  to what? Compared to QCT? That's no wonder, because as I have already tried to point out, QCT and TST are inherently different methods. Another source of confusion might be with lifetime and half-life. Lifetime is just the reciprocal of the rate coefficient, while half-life is ln(2) divided by the coefficient.

Comment: no, off compared to their TST calculated values if I take their barriers and calculate the lifetime as reciprocal of the rate constant using eyring equation. For example the anti pathway for the reaction of tetrazine with cyclopropene they got a barrier of 2.3kcal/mol according to that paper and a lifetime of 6794 fs. Now with 2.3kcal/mol I get around 7600 fs. I looked at the supporting information and calculated the barrier from the calculated energies and I get a barrier of 2.218 kcal/mol and with that a lifetime of 6805 fs (the difference has to be just accuracy of the used constants)

Comment: Just dropping in a question here: is it common practice in theoretical organic chem to use the Eyring equation and call it transition state theory? I myself have some research experience in reaction dynamics of small systems (like atom + diatom reactions), and when I say TST, I  do not mean Eyring's equation, which is - as far as I know - correctly termed as activated complex theory. This might seem nuisance, but I've been thinking about picking up reactions like this. I have always been fascinated by Diels-Alder, and I think it is not well understood - so I am asking it for my clarity.

Comment: yes it is.  Activated complex theory is basically just another name for TST and Eyring equation is the way to go ( IUPAC goldbook shows the eyring euqation in their entry of TST: http://goldbook.iupac.org/html/T/T06470.html ). There are very small differences in the definition of "activated complex" and "transition state" but practically they are the same. But to keep it clean here I'm happy to discuss this further in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59073/discussion-between-dsva-and-ezze).

Comment: One thing to consider is that the TS can, if the reaction is indeed elementary, go back to the reactants as well as products (which is contary to the assumptions in rigorous TST). Make sure you consider the rate constant for the reverse process in your lifetime calculation (ie take the inverse of the forward and reverse rate constants) - it might well account for the ~800 fs...